# Why does *ngIF always evaluate to true in my Angular app?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-ng-if

I define `Todo` as follows:

```
export class Todo {
  id: number;
  title: string;
  complete: boolean = false;
  editMode: boolean = false;
  }
```

I have the following data service:

```
  getAllTodos(): Observable<Array<Todo>> {
     return this.aHttpService.get<Array<Todo>>('http://localhost:3000/todos');
  }
```

Then, I have this component:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { TodoDataService } from '../todo-data.service';
import { Todo } from '../todo';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-all-tasks',
  templateUrl: './all-tasks.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-tasks.component.css']
})
export class AllTasksComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private todoDataService: TodoDataService) {}
  allTodos: Observable<Array<Todo>>;

  ngOnInit() {
    this.allTodos = this.todoDataService.getAllTodos();
  }
}
```

and in the template I have:

```
<li *ngFor="let todo of allTodos | async" >
  <span *ngIf="todo.complete; else elseBlock"><span>&#10003;</span></span>
  <ng-template #elseBlock>
    <span>&#x2715;</span>
  </ng-template>
  <span>{{todo.title}}</span>
</li>
```

However `todo.complete` always evaluates to `true`, despite the fact that the incoming data isn't always `true`. (I validate that via a call to the service with Postman...)

Why is the value always `true`?

I should note that the `todo.title` renders correctly.

**Update**

A call to `http://localhost:3000/todos` via Postman returns:

```
[
{
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Learn TypeScript",
    "complete": "true",
    "editMode": "false"
},
{
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Learn Angular changed",
    "complete": "true",
    "editMode": "false"
},
{
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Learn to Read",
    "complete": "true",
    "editMode": "false"
},
{
    "id": 4,
    "title": "Learn to Write",
    "complete": "false",
    "editMode": "false"
},
{
    "title": "Learn how to type",
    "complete": "true",
    "editMode": "false",
    "id": 5
},
{
    "title": "Learn how to drive",
    "complete": "false",
    "editMode": "false",
    "id": 6
}
]
```

Comment: could you please check the value of isComplete by subscribe the service from the component itself this.todoDataService.getAllTodos().subscribe((response)=>{ console.log(response)});

Comment: Have you tried *ngIf="todo.complete == true"

Comment: @Marshal -- Huh, doing that causes them to all evaluate `false`.

Comment: Can you post a sample of your data?

Comment: @NickHodges you mentioned that the incoming data isn't always true... without an example of your data, I guess I just assumed you were defaulting the value to false if not present.

Comment: @JameelM -- I checked the values in the console as you suggested and they are as expected -- some `true` and some `false`.

Comment: @NickHodges although my comment was close, I just assumed the value was boolean and not a string.

Comment: @Marshal -- Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I was sure `complete` was coming as a `string` instead of a `boolean`.

Since a string in `*ngIf`(and generally in a JavaScript `if(...)`) always resolves to `true`(as long as it's not empty(`''`)), the `*ngIf` block was always getting displayed on the screen and `elseBlock` was not.

Use this to fix it:

```
<span *ngIf="todo.complete === 'true'; else elseBlock"><span>&#10003;</span></span>
```

Comment: Yep, that did it.  Thanks.

Comment: "Since a string in *ngIf always resolves to true". It has little to do with `ngIf`, it's just regular JavaScript coercion: `if ("true")` and `if ("false")` would both take the true-branch

Comment: @LazarLjubenović, I'm sorry but I was talking in the context of the issue at hand. I'll update the answer accordingly. Thanks for your inputs. :)

Comment: Thanks @ConnorsFan,. Fixed :)